# Can my supervisor prevent me from publishing by affecting reviewers opinion?

Tags: thesis, peer-review

Lately, and after long time of work in my PhD, I was able to get a result that is brand new, very strong and important. My supervisor though seems jealous and wants me not to publish before finishing my PhD. But I sense he wants to scoop me once I leave. The time is short and I haven't enough time to work in lab that will guarantee a paper. I insist on publishing though, can he contact any of the journal editors and affect their opinion?
I can't take the risk, so what should I do to avoid this?

Comment: Is there some reason why you wouldn't expect to publish together with your supervisor as a co-author?  Or at least put the material into your thesis, where it's date-stamped and clearly associated with your name?

Comment: What's your field? Usually an advisor is added as a co-author to papers resulted directly from a PhD. If this is the case, why would he jeopardize his chances to getting some publications?

Comment: Obligatory "it isn't automatic that advisors are coauthors on mathematics graduate students' papers" comment. So, it really would be helpful to specify what field you're in.

Comment: The reason is because it is a new result that he seems a bit jealous of me getting it. I am working in biofuel and deforestation, so mainly biology.
He won't say not to publish but I know he might do everything to stop it or at least to slower it till he does some work based on mine and publish.
He ofcourse want to publish , but I guess he wants to be first name that publish this work. Simply, to be a first author and not second.

Comment: Either your advisor is planning on scooping your result, or your distrust your advisor so much that you think they're planning to scoop your result even then they aren't.  **How did you and your advisor develop such a horribly dysfunctional relationship?**

Comment: :) There is no place here really for opening that subject. But you are truly right, it is horrible and it got worst once I got this result :) let's say, he has issues! which I got to know later, I used to explain in a way that excluded the bad truth about him. So am trying to be positive as only few months left for me to finish my PhD, but also I will try to get the most of them. Jakebeal's suggestion is great, perhaps to do all the work i can to include in my thesis, and this will give me some time to finish writing up, viva. Then make a nice paper out of this work no matter what he plans to.

Answer (score 3):

In a biology / bio-engineering discipline, the authorship standards almost certainly dictate that you must have your supervisor as a co-author.
As such, worrying about contacting journal editors is beside the point: you *can't* ethically publish without your supervisor's permission---not because they're your supervisor, but because they're your co-author.

The biology focus also may help explain your supervisor's reluctance to publish, as it's (unfortunately) common for biologists to spend years building up a "perfect publication" with no incremental publications in order to try to get into a "glamour" journal like Nature or Science.

Given this context, I would recommend simply including the work you've done in your Ph.D. thesis (which does not preclude glamour publication).  That will make it very clear that you have done the work, such that your name must remain attached to it.  Beyond that point, I would recommend not worrying about the author order either: in biology, it is typical to put the student first and the supervisor last; since "last author" is also a significant and prominent position, I would expect that your supervisor is unlikely to have a problem with you being first.

Finally, I would recommend that you have a clear discussion with your supervisor about the criteria for publication.  Not "when will we publish?" because the answer to that will probably be "when it's ready," but "what else needs to be done before we publish?"  Get that agreement clearly worked out between you, then confirm it afterward via email to create a timestamped written record, and then you can also feel it is less likely that publication can be delayed by shifting goalposts.

Answer (score 1):

> can he contact any of the journal editors and affect their opinion?

To answer your direct question first: this is very unlikely. If he doesn't know the journal that you are planning on submitting to (and if you choose to go ahead as a single author there is no reason he would) then there are just too many possible editors out there. He would have much to lose in terms of reputation if he were to contact dozens of editors and warn them against accepting a paper that he doesn't even know has been submitted to them. Even if he does know which editor is handling your paper, unless that editor is a mate of his and has questionable ethics, they are likely to judge the paper on its merits rather than be swayed by a third party butting in.

> But I sense he wants to scoop me once I leave.

If he were to do this, surely it would be very easy to prove that this was your work? Even before it is included in your thesis, don't you have lab notes etc. that show you have been working on this topic? If he tried to publish it without your name on the paper, you would have a strong case to demonstrate his misconduct.

Finally, is it possible that you have exaggerated the issues in your head? Much of your question is based on "My supervisor *seems*...", "*I sense*...", "*I guess*...". Have you actually talked to your supervisor about these things? I think that by far the best outcome, for both of you, would be to publish a joint paper. Do you know for sure that he will not accept that option? Or perhaps there is a good reason that he thinks you should delay publication. I would suggest addressing these questions first before jumping to conclusions.

Comment: The thing is not him publishing my work, it's him publishing work based on mine before I do myself. I know he can't just go publish my own work but he will simply probably add me as a second author or so.
Since I am trapped with final months in my PhD I barely have time to work in lab for completing some work that should be enough to publish.
If I will put his name on the paper as a co-author, I will have to tell him which journal is it going to be. Unless there is another way out of it that I don't know.

Comment: Yup, unfortunately, it is based on sense. But I know his character and i know that he is the kind of person that could do this, he is not the best supervisor and I am stuck with him anyways. Besides, he will ofcourse never say directly he will publish.
These conclusions are  based on personal experiences with him and not emotional or overthinking by me. 
So for now I try to finish peacefully, but I guess it can't be peaceful when you get a result!

Comment: A submitted paper must have the permission of all listed authors. It is not possible for your supervisor to add you as an author without your direct permission. And it is not possible for him to publish your work without adding you as an author. If he does either of these things, you have every right to complain to the journal and have the paper withdrawn.

Comment: Seems tempting to let him do that and make it a problem :)
But really, it's about who will be the first author, and he is planning to. 
So I am searching a way ot keep my right as a first author until i finish writing up my thesis.